# How do I find the correct file path for assetManager.openFd()?

Tags: java, android, io

I have a file stored in an Android project like this:

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(id);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, name));
ByteStreams.copy(in, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Where dir is: `/data/user/0/com.aaa.app/files/media` and name is: `my_file`.

But, I am getting a FileNotFoundException (thrown from assetManager.openFd()) when I try the following:

```
private ParcelFileDescriptor getSeekableFileDescriptor() {
    Context context = getContext();
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor;
    ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
    try {
        assetFileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd("/data/user/0/com.aaa.app/files/media/my_file");
        fileDescriptor = assetFileDescriptor.getParcelFileDescriptor();
        return fileDescriptor;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    return fileDescriptor;
}
```

I have also tried passing the following to openFd():

```
"data/user/0/com.aaa.app/files/media/my_file",
"/media/my_file",
"media/my_file",
"/my_file",
"my_file"
```

Then I added ".pdf" to each of the above. Still no success. I get FileNotFound for each of the above.

Comment: `AssetManager` is for opening assets. `AssetFileDescriptor` is for assets. Your file is not an asset. Why are you trying to create an `AssetFileDescriptor`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Ultimately, I'm trying to render a pdf using: PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor()); So I'm trying to get a ParcelFileDescriptor back from the getSeekableFileDescriptor() method. Why do you say my file is not an asset? I do not understand the distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do you say my file is not an asset?

Because it is not an asset. An asset is part of your app (e.g., `src/main/assets/`) and is packaged in your APK.

> So I'm trying to get a ParcelFileDescriptor

Use [`open()` on `ParcelFileDescriptor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#open(java.io.File,%20int)) to open a `ParcelFileDescriptor` on a `File`.